# How to scrape a whole website using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm quite new to Programming and OO programming especially. Nonetheless, I'm trying to write a very simple Spider for web crawling. Here's my first approach:

I need to fetch the data out of this page: http://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation_en

Firstly, I do a view on the page source to find HTML elements?
[view-source:https://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation_en](http://view-source:https://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation_en)

**Note:** I need to fetch the data that comes right below this line:

#### EVS accredited organisations search results: 6066

I chose beautiful soup for this job - since it is very powerful:

I Use find_all:

```
soup.find_all('p')[0].get_text() # Searching for tags by class and id
```

Note: Classes and IDs are used by CSS to determine which HTML elements to apply certain styles to. We can also use them when scraping to specify specific elements we want to scrape.

See the class:

```
                  <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="vp ey_block block-is-flex">
  <div class="ey_inner_block">
    <h4 class="text-center"><a href="/youth/volunteering/organisation/935175449_en" target="_blank">&quot;People need people&quot; Zaporizhya oblast civic organisation of disabled families</a></h4>
            <p class="ey_info">
    <i class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-lg"></i>
    Zaporizhzhya, <strong>Ukraine</strong>
</p>    <p class="ey_info"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right fa-lg"></i> Sending</p>
                  <p><strong>PIC no:</strong> 935175449</p>
        <div class="empty-block">
      <a href="/youth/volunteering/organisation/935175449_en" target="_blank" class="ey_btn btn btn-default pull-right">Read more</a>    </div>
  </div>
```

so this leads to:

```
# import libraries
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation_en")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup
```

Now, we can use the find_all method to search for items by class or by id. In the below example, we'll search for any p tag that has the class outer-text

```
<div class="col-md-4">
```

so we choose:

```
soup.find_all(class_="col-md-4")
```

Now I have to combine all.

update: **my approach:** so far:

I have extracted data wrapped within multiple HTML tags from a webpage using BeautifulSoup4. I want to store all of the extracted data in a list. And - to be more concrete: I want each of the extracted data as separate list elements separated by a comma (i.e.CSV-formated).

To begin with the beginning:

here we have the **HTML content structure:**

```
 <div class="view-content">
            <div class="row is-flex"></span>
                 <div class="col-md-4"></span>
            <div class </span>
  <div class= >
    <h4 Data 1 </span>
          <div class= Data 2</span>
            <p class=
    <i class=
     <strong>Data 3 </span>
</p>    <p class= Data 4 </span>
          <p class= Data 5 </span>
                  <p><strong>Data 6</span>
        <div class=</span>
      <a href="Data 7</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code to extract:**

```
for data in elem.find_all('span', class_=""):
```

This should give an output:

```
data = [ele.text for ele in soup.find_all('span', {'class':'NormalTextrun'})]
print(data)
```

**Output:**
[' Data 1 ', ' Data 2 ', ' Data 3 ' and so forth]

**question:** / i need help with the extraction part...

Comment: So, what's the question? Which part do you need help with?

Comment: hello dear Keyur - to be frank: i am a Python /& BS beginner I have just some tutorial - background. If you could lend a helping hand with the next steps i have to accomplish and to do. I need somewhat an approach. Can you help me here in giving me a help - that i can go on ... - love to hear from you - malaga

Comment: You said `now i have to combine all.`. Can you explain exactly what you want to do? People here on SO will gladly help you, after you provide an MCVE. Read- [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, I'm sorry if I overlooked something and didn't get your exact question.

Comment: dear Keyur - again many many thanks. I have added some bits and tried to deliver a minimal comlpete and verifiable example. In other words: i ve tried to gather all i have so that we can discuss the approach. If you can have a closer look at the part of the data - extraction with BS4  i would be more than glad. - kind regards Malaga

Comment: dear malaga - u gotta hear upon keyur - i think that he is quite right. You gotta need to give us a glimpse of the source code u wanna parse

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
data = [ele.text for ele in soup.find_all(text = True) if ele.text.strip() != '']
print(data)
```